# How to change ts file based on language using angular localization

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular-i18n

I have files `errors.ts` and `content.ts` with English content same way `errorsEs.ts` and `contentEs.ts` with Spanish content.etc. I am doing `JIT compiler angular localization` to translate the language. I have imported `errors.ts` and `content.ts` throughout the app.

As of now, I am replacing the translated language(Spanish, Italian) content into the English `content.ts` and `errors.ts` to run it as a different language. Is there any other way to do it without replacement of files?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create translation files with locales in the name (I'll create one for the sake of the example) :

**error.en-US.ts**

```
export const errors = {
  http: {
    e404: `Error: resource not found on the server`
  }
};
```

Next, create an error service. In the constructor, get the user locale, load the file, then use it :

```
constructor() {
  if (window.navigator.languages) { this.language = window.navigator.languages[0]; } 
  else { this.language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language; }

  this.errors = require(`errors.${this.language}`).errors;
}
```

#### EDIT

```js
console.log(window.navigator.languages);
console.log(window.navigator.userLanguage);
console.log(window.navigator.language);
```

Comment: (I must state that I do it from memory, you will have to adapt this to your own code, but it's totally doable)

Comment: what is that language array hold of?

Comment: The locales, users usually have several of them with a pound for each of them. For instance, mine is `["fr-FR", "fr", "en-US", "en"]`

Comment: Property 'languages' does not exist on type 'Navigator'. Property 'userLanguage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'. I am getting this errors?

Comment: You didn't use my code. If you did, `if (window.navigator.languages)` would have prevented that. The condition isn't there to be pretty ...